# Store returned result to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, return, store

How can I store the returned result into a variable without it being changed? I basically want the function to be only called once and be stored in the variable.

Right now the var `word` changes its value each time I press the button. I want it to get the retired value from the `read()` function and keep the value the same for validation

Here is my code:

```
function read() {
    // var result gets a random line from a file
    var lines = result.split(", ");
    var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
    return lines[randLineNum];
}

function Check(strParam){
        var guessWord = strParam;
        var word = read();
        if(guessWord != ""){
            if(guessWord !== word){
                console.log(word); // I am checking here for the word and it keeps changing
            }
        }
    }

$('#button').on('click', function() {
    Check($('#txtbox').val());
});
```

Comment: Really not clear what you are wanting to do. Please expand on desired behavior and objective. Function should only be called once per click, if that is not wanted try using `one()` or calling `off()`

Comment: @charlietfl check now :)

Comment: keep the value and do what when button gets clicked again?

Comment: compare it with guessWord var... which I can do by myself @charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function read() {
    // var result gets a random line from a file
    var lines = result.split(", ");
    var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
    return lines[randLineNum];
}

var word = read();

function Check(strParam){
        var guessWord = strParam;        
        if(guessWord != ""){
            if(guessWord !== word){
                // I am checking here for the word and it keeps changing
                console.log(word); 
            }
        }
    }

$('#button').on('click', function() {
    Check($('#txtbox').val());
});
```

Comment: Works... i see my mistake... WOW! easy fix! thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var lines = result.split(", ");
var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
var word = lines[randLineNum];

function Check(strParam){
    var guessWord = strParam;
    if(guessWord != ""){
        if(guessWord !== word){
            console.log(word); // I am checking here for the word and it keeps changing
        }
    }
}

$('#button').on('click', function() {
     Check($('#txtbox').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Evertime you click the Button , the OnClick Function calls read which does what its exactly supposed to do . Choose a random line from the file . You need to cache the result before checking it .

```
function read() {
    // var result gets a random line from a file
    var lines = result.split(", ");
    var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
    return lines[randLineNum];
}

var word = read();

function Check(strParam){
    var guessWord = strParam;
    //var word = read();  
    if(guessWord != ""){
        if(guessWord !== word){
            console.log(word); 
        }
    }

 }

$('#button').on('click', function() {
    Check($('#txtbox').val());
});
```